# Need help in properly writing an XML LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, linq

XML Snippet

```
  <GameList>
  <Game>
    <GameDefinitiongameID>{1b2e4ff7-ddd3-4fe3-9fdf-6b2ee240d18c}</GameDefinitiongameID>
    <WMID>{01bc5c01-923d-4efb-bba6-49e93b2694ab}</WMID>
    <VersionNumberversionNumber>1.0.0.0</VersionNumberversionNumber>
    <Title>JamesBond007:Nightfire</Title>
    <GameExecutablepath>\easupport\go_ez.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <GameExecutablepath>\easupport\jamesbond007nightfire_code.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <GameExecutablepath>\easupport\jamesbond007nightfire_ereg.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <GameExecutablepath>\easupport\jamesbond007nightfire_ez.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <GameExecutablepath>jamesbond007nightfire_uninst.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <GameExecutablepath>unwise.exe</GameExecutablepath>
    <RatingratingID>{CEC5DB5A-B4C9-4809-96C6-39CE715E4790}</RatingratingID>
    <ratingSystemID>{36798944-B235-48ac-BF21-E25671F597EE}</ratingSystemID>
    <DescriptordescriptorID>{F110F831-9412-40c9-860A-B489407ED374}</DescriptordescriptorID>
    <RatingratingID>{18CD34B7-7AA3-42b9-A303-5A729B2FF228}</RatingratingID>
    <ratingSystemID>{768BD93D-63BE-46A9-8994-0B53C4B5248F}</ratingSystemID>
    <DescriptordescriptorID>{B54162A2-F67F-46dc-9ED5-F6067520EC94}</DescriptordescriptorID>
    <DescriptordescriptorID>{BE562A5F-2A80-4c28-9752-74C696E2ABAF}</DescriptordescriptorID>
  </Game>
```

and so on.

I used the following to query this file

```
Dim members = From m In GameXml.Element("GameList").Elements("Game")
        Where m.Element("Title").Value.ToLower.Contains(Name) = True
                Select m.Descendants
```

"Name" is the variable containing the search string.

Now, how to I get all the info (as array of strings or any other parse-able format) from the "members" variable.

I am new to XML and LINQ.

I am OK with both C# and VB.Net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know what exact properties it has you can do this:

```
dynamic members = from m In GameXml.Element("GameList").Elements("Game")
        where m.Element("Title").Value.ToLower.Contains(Name) = True
                select m;
```

now you can use: `members.ratingSystemID`

But if you know the properties you can create a class like:

```
public class Game{
public string Title{set; get; }
public string Name {get; set;}
.
.
.
}
```

and then:

```
List<Game> members = from m In GameXml.Element("GameList").Elements("Game")
            where m.Element("Title").Value.ToLower.Contains(Name) = True
                    select new {Title = m.Title, Name = m.Name, ...};
```

so you can use it like `Members[0].Title`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get `Game` node, you're so close:

```
Dim members = From m In GameXml.Element("GameList").Elements("Game")
     Where m.Element("Title").Value.ToLower.Contains(Name) = True
     Select m.Descendants("Game")
```

or (C#):

```
var members = GameXml.Descendants("Game")
      .Where(g=>g.Element("Title").Value.ToLower().Contains("Whatever"));
```